# Determining Max and Min number of nodes for AVL and Red Black trees

Tags: avl-tree, red-black-tree

Is there a way to easily determine the max and minimum number of nodes in an AVL or Red Black tree given just the tree height and/or the black height(in the case of the Red Black Tree)?

Comment: Is this your homework ?

Comment: You can calculate it yourself using the property of RedBlackTrees: _the path from the root to the farthest leaf is no more than twice as long as the path from the root to the nearest leaf_

Comment: @c69 its a problem on a practice exam and I am trying to understand the answer so i can learn it...

Comment: The best way to learn is to find the answer yourself. Read the quote from wiki again - you will see quite a simple mathematical relation. DepthMax <= DepthMin*2,  and of course each node has at max 2 sub-nodes.